# Should I use all my storage on bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp

So I'm a gamer, and I will only use bootcamp and probably never use MacOS ever again. Should I "wipe" my mac to free up as much storage as I can to use all of the storage for bootcamp? I have 1TB of space, and I would like to use as much of that as possible for my windows partition. Would this cause any problems on my mac or windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is certainly possible and even practical to entirely wipe macOS from any Boot Camp supporting Mac I often leave a small (10-20GB) partition with macOS on it to keep around in case there are problems with Windows or the Mac itself strictly for troubleshooting purposes.

However that is a personal preference and there is really no technical reason to not dedicate the entire disk to Windows. Your call.

Comment: I would add that for 2015 and newer Macs, you would need the Boot Camp Assistant application to download the Windows Support Software (i.e. the Windows drivers) before erasing macOS from your Mac.

Comment: Would wiping my mac also delete the bootcamp save?

Comment: What you would do with the Windows Support Software depends on whether you wish to install Windows with or without the use of a flash drive. I assume you have a fairly new Mac. The requirements for the older Mac are a lot more stringent. What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of Windows are you going to install? Is Windows 32 or 64 bit? What is the current version of macOS? All of these things matter.